# Function Movement. Processing

Tags: javascript, processing

So I have a game that I am making and it involves shooting things at the player to try to get them to lose hearts. I need to write a function for Attack Right, Attack Left, Attack Down, and Attack Up. The problem is that once the function executes, and say I give it a x, a y, and a speed input, I want it to create a rectangle with the coordinates (x,y,50,10)
After I draw the rectangle, and say the function that was called was attack right, was to update the x based on the speed. Like:

rect(x,y,50,10)

x=speed+x;

For some reason when I call it though, it only executes once, when I want it to loop over and over again. When I put it in a draw loop, it just resets the function. Ideas?

PS: If I need to make it clearer, just ask me.

Comment: You need to make it clearer. Please show enough code to provide a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: If you are making a game and can use a framework, I would highly recommend using an existing one for physics and general game architecture such as phaser.js (http://phaser.io/). The process will be much easier without having to reinvent the wheel, as simple things like what you are attempting are handled by most frameworks.

Comment: I don't think you need to use a framework (in fact, Processing already does a lot of the stuff a different framework would), but you do need to provide a [mcve].